# Is there a closure in this function?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

This function that I got from here (http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#19), even though it doesn't have any inner function that persists with a "record" of the values passed in after the outer function ends, has some type of data caching. In fact the values in the cache property persist after any call to the function. I wonder if this is a type of closure:

```
function getElements( name ) { 
  var results; 

  if ( getElements.cache[name] ) { 
    results = getElements.cache[name]; 
  } else { 
    results = document.getElementsByTagName(name); 
    getElements.cache[name] = results; 
  } 

  return results; 
} 
getElements.cache = {};
```

I'm not sure if it applies to function properties or only to referenced functions. I'm still too confused about closures, so maybe I'm talking nonsense.

Comment: That's just a property on a function object. Nothing to do with closures.

Comment: Note that personally I would remove the `getElements.cache = {};` line and have it inside the function itself: `getElements.cache = getElements.cache || {};` - This way if I want to move the function elsewhere I don't need to remember the line after it.

Comment: @Kolink: Thanks for the advice. It worked and it's definitely better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no closure, but a function, like any other javascript object, can receive properties and that's what happens here.

`getElements` is an object so you can assign a value to `getElements.cache`.

That's another way of not cluttering the global namespace, probably a little lighter than using a closure, but a little less clean as the property isn't private (it can be easily accessed) and (very theoretically) could lead to a name conflict.

Comment: That's very explanatory. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Any function in Javascript is an object. The `cache` property that is stored on the `getElements` function is the same for all invocations of the function.

No closure is involved here.